# Scoring how much string relates to text

Tags: python, php, data-analysis, data-extraction

I've got a list of job titles:

`["Teacher English", "Teacher Spanish", "Teacher first grade"]`

And I've got a job description from a random job listing:

`"Teacher Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras non urna tincidunt, rutrum velit ut, bibendum massa. Duis sed enim nec Teacher magna bibendum aliquet. Duis massa turpis, faucibus placerat viverra nec, imperdiet sed arcu. Pellentesque justo tellus, vehicula vel lacinia sit English amet, sodales ac mauris. Donec iaculis quis augue sed First tempus. Suspendisse potenti. Cras egestas suscipit magna, ut lacinia mauris eleifend quis. Curabitur nisl lorem, pretium nec libero viverra, Teacher maximus vulputate orci. Suspendisse volutpat massa id felis imperdiet tincidunt."`

For each of the job titles, I want a score which consist of how much they correlate with the job description. So the result might be:

```
[
  [0] => [
          "job_title" => "Teacher English",
          "score" => 9.8
         ],
  [1] => [
          "job_title" => "Teacher Spanish",
          "score" => 5.22
         ],
  [2] => [
          "job_title" => "Teacher first grade",
          "score" => 6.457
         ]
]
```

How higher the score, how more the job title and job description correlate.

Does anyone now a library that I can use for this problem?

The programming language doesn't really matter. But preferably Python or PHP.

Comment: possibly [levenshtein distance](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) You'd need to do some pre-parsing of the text though, max chars is 255.

Comment: @berend Levenshtein won't work in this case, since it's a large text vs a word.
OP, your assignment is wrong, since like 96.5% of your text is Latin. You can try to search for words (like english, spanish, first, grade ...) and base your result on top of that, but it won't be as accurate as you'd like it to be.

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh the text is is lorem ipsum with some words like "Teacher", "first" and "English". Searching for the words might become a problem when using small words like "and" in a job title. Since "and" will appear quite a lot in the text.